# Start in folder with dot.net execution (batch file)

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd

I would like to execute the following, but I would like to be able to move the app to any location and the file client_secrets.json will be always in the same folder. The statement should be called from the root (d:). Is there a way to specify a start in (work) folder?

```
d:\> dotnet D:\projects\Test\Test.GoogleSheets\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Test.GoogleSheets.dll
```

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\client_secret.json'.
File name: 'D:\client_secret.json'
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at Test.GoogleSheets.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\projects\Test\Test.GoogleSheets\Program.cs:line 33
```

Answer (score 0):

The default directory that things such as [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=net-5.0) is the current working directory(the directory the `.exe` or `.dll` are located in)

The way this works is in C# there are two kinds of paths that are used by the program for paramaters, such as the paramater for `FileStream`.

[There are **Absolute paths** and **Relative paths**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-5.0#remarks)

**Absolute paths**
These paths fully specify a location: the file or directory can be uniquely identified regardless of the current location.

An example of a absolute path would be

```
'D:\client_secret.json'
```

**Relative paths**
These paths specify a partial location: **the current location is used as the starting point** when locating a file specified with a relative path.

One example would be

```
/Data/game_data.bin
```

In the above example we would be using the `game_data.bin` file in the `Data` folder. The `Data` folder would be in the same directory as the `.exe`(or `.dll`)

Or say we wanted to reference a file in a folder above us. We could use the `../` file path to say "this is something above me".

Such as

```
../../Readme.md
```

This would be the `Readme.md` file located in the parent folder of **our**(the `.exe`/`.dll`) parent folder, so two folders up.

So for your example if `client_secret.json` is always located in the same folder as the `.exe` or `.dll` the solution is fairly simple.

Instead of using `D:\client_secret.json` just use `client_secret.json` and it will always look at the current directory first.

Here's an example of how it would look in practice

```cs
byte[] nums = new byte[9];

using FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("client_secret.json");

fs.Read(nums, 0, nums.Length);

fs.Close();

fs.Dispose();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", nums));
```